# E: Unable to locate package openjdk-11-jdk on dockerfile

Tags: python, dockerfile

I have problem, my dockerfile, cant install openjdk-11-jdk, before my script is doing well, but when I want to run again, its problem, my script on dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        openjdk-11-jdk


ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/
ENV PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Thank you

Dockerfile can doing well to run my apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you have to change the `FROM` instruction since the default image for `python:3.7` is `bookworm` and `openjdk-11-jdk` is available on `bullseye`:

```
FROM python:3.7-bullseye

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        openjdk-11-jdk


ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/
ENV PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Or for a lightweight image, use `python:3.7-slim-bullseye`.

Comment: Thank you, Corralien. My problem is solve.